# How to merge multiple CSV files into one, with only unique values

Tags: ruby, csv

I have multiple CSV files in a directory, all with the same data model, some of which are duplicate entires.

file1.csv:

```
1       joe      red
2       bill     blue 
3       bob      green
```

file2.csv:

```
3       bob      green
4       mary     white 
5       jim      yellow
```

file3.csv:

```
5       jim      yellow
6       lauren    pink  
7       george    purple
```

My goal is to produce a single CSV file of all the unique values.

So far the code I have is this:

1. Concatenated all the files in iTerm2 using

   ```
    cat *.csv > combined.csv
   ```
2. And this script:

   ```
   require 'csv'

   File.open("all_unique_rows.csv", "w+") { 

     |file| file.puts File.readlines("combined.csv").uniq 

   }
   ```

However, I want to be able to do this all from a single Ruby script, however I'm just not sure how to make the "combined.csv" file one giant file using Ruby.

Comment: These are not CSV files. Most likely they're fixed-width, but could be TSV though your third sample has skewed columns for the last two records.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't do this in Ruby if your records are true duplicates. Instead, take advantage of existing tools in the OS made for this:

```
cat *.csv | sort -u >unique.csv
```

When finished, "unique.csv" will contain the unique records.

If you insist in writing it in Ruby, then take advantage of built-in methods or classes. Here is one untested way to do it:

```
require 'set'
unique = Set.new
Dir.glob('*.csv') do |f|
  File.foreach(f) { |l| unique << l }
end
File.write('unique.csv', unique.sort.join)
```

This works to create a unique output because Sets don't allow duplicates.

An alternate way is to do something like:

```
unique = []
Dir.glob('*.csv') do |f|
  unique += File.readlines(f)
end
File.write('unique.csv', unique.sort.uniq.join)
```

While Ruby *can* do this, using the OS to handle it is much more scalable. YMMV.

---

> I tried running cat *.csv | sort - u > unique.csv in OS, but ended up with some values misplaced into the wrong columns.

I created the three files on my disk:

```
$ cat file1.csv
1       joe      red
2       bill     blue
3       bob      green
```

```
$ cat file2.csv
3       bob      green
4       mary     white
5       jim      yellow
```

```
$ cat file3.csv
5       jim      yellow
6       lauren    pink
7       george    purple
```

Running `cat *.csv | sort -u >unique.csv` and looking at the resulting file shows:

```
$ cat unique.csv
1       joe      red
2       bill     blue
3       bob      green
4       mary     white
5       jim      yellow
6       lauren    pink
7       george    purple
```

The duplicates are removed, and the file is identical to the input samples you gave. Your "file3.csv" shows an extra space in the last to lines, pushing the right-most column over.

*Note*: Your files are *NOT* CSV files. CSV stands for "comma-separated values" and there are no commas between your columns. It is possible you originally had TSV ("tab-separated values"), which Ruby's CSV class can read and write, or you had fixed-width columns and somehow added an extra space. It's really important to use the right terminology and do it consistently, especially when asking questions.

Comment: I tried running `cat *.csv | sort - u > unique.csv` in OS, but ended up with some values misplaced into the wrong columns.

Comment: If they're in the wrong columns check the input files. There's nothing in the OS commands that can possibly change the columns. Those commands only work on complete lines.

Comment: `unique << l` pushes a line to the end of the array.